# How to generate primary key from sequence in HSQLDB

Tags: sql, sequence, hsqldb

Currently I am using HSQLDB 2.0.0 for my project.

I have a table with primary key and a sequence.

I would like to generate the primary key value from the sequence whenever a insert happens.

Is that possible by a trigger? If so  could you let me know how this can be accomplished?

Regards,

Satya

Comment: possible duplicate of [Link a sequence with to an identity in hsqldb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954045/link-a-sequence-with-to-an-identity-in-hsqldb)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with a trigger. See this question

[Link a sequence with to an identity in hsqldb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954045/link-a-sequence-with-to-an-identity-in-hsqldb)